# AWS AppSync Error: Template transformation yielded an empty response

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, webapi

I have a .Net Core GraphQL API deployed outside of AWS cloud. I am trying integrate AWS AppSync with my GraphQL API.

Schema:

```
  type TestData {
           StduentId: String
           StduentName: String
       }

  type Query {
      TestFunction(
             departmentId: String,
             departmentCity: String,
           ): [TestData]
    }

  schema {
           query: Query
         }
```

I am running the below query in AWS AppSync Console.

```
query
{
   TestFunction(
                 departmentId:"124",
                 departmentCity: "Boston"
               ) 
   {
       StduentId
       StudentName
   }

}
```

Request Mapping Template:

```
    {
        "version": "2018-05-29",
        "method": "GET",
        "resourcePath": "/",
        "params":{
        "query":$util.toJson($ctx.args),
         "headers": {
                       "Authorization": "$ctx.request.headers.Authorization"
                    }
            }
       }
```

Response mapping template.

```
#if($ctx.error)
   $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
   $util.toJson($context.result),
#else
   $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

AppSync: Datasource Resource is :

```
https://myserver.com/graphql/
```

I am expecting the nested JSON output from the above query execution.

Query Response:
"errorType": "MappingTemplate",
"message": "Template transformation yielded an empty response."

CloudWatch Error:
"message": "A custom error was thrown from a mapping template.",

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to create an http resolver to a REST api? Im not sure why you have a /graphql in your path?

for HTTP REST resolver in appsync your datasource should end in ".com". Something like https://myserver.com

then in your request template the resource path completes the specified resource:

{
"version": "2018-05-29",
"method": "GET",
"resourcePath": "/v1/api/some-resource",
"params":{
"query":$util.toJson($ctx.args),
"headers": {
"Authorization": "$ctx.request.headers.Authorization"
}
}
}

response mapping template would look like:

```
#if($ctx.error)
   $util.error($ctx.error`enter code here`.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
   #set($body = $util.parseJson($ctx.result.body))
    $util.toJson($body) #make it $body.data depending on the return on your rest api
#else
   $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

Comment: My actual URL is like : https://myserver.com:12345.  I have updated the response mapping, but it still not working.  But some thing looks better . Error ""message": "Lexical error,   Encountered: \"`\" (96), after : \"\" at *unset*[line 2, column 26]""

Comment: I am expecting the TestData in nested Json. (The Function Return Type is List(TestData)